# typescript type conditionals extends object

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I would like to have conditional type that something is an object.

```
type Id = {
    id: number
    obj: {
        x: 5
    }
}

type ObjString<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]:
        T[P] extends Object ? string : T[P]
}


const f: ObjString<Id> = {
    id: 4,
    obj: "xxxx"
}
```

here, the `obj` property is correctly mapped to string in the `f` object, but for the `id` property, I'll get this error message:

```
error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

That means that `T[P] extends Object` is evaluated to true for `number`. How should I construct the condition, so number will evaluate to false, whereas object would evaluate to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object` type does not really correspond to non-primitives in TypeScript; rather it is the type of a values which can be indexed into like an object.  This includes primitives like `string` and `number`, which get [wrapped with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#primitive_wrapper_objects_in_javascript) when you index into them (and thus supports things like `"hello".toUpperCase()` and `(123).toFixed(2)`).  Only `null` and `undefined` are not `Object`s in this sense.  [`Object` in TypeScript is rarely what you want](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).

If you are trying to find a type in TypeScript which means "non-primitive", you can use [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) instead (starts with a lowercase `o` instead of an uppercase `O`):

```
type ObjString<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]:
  T[P] extends object ? string : T[P]
}

type Z = ObjString<Id>;
/* type Z = {
    id: number;
    obj: string;
} */

const f: ObjString<Id> = {
  id: 4,
  obj: "xxxx"
}
```

And then everything works how you want here.

Keep in mind though that arrays and functions are also `object`s, so you might get some undesirable behavior depending on what you wanted to see there:

```
type Hmm = ObjString<{ foo(): string, bar: number[] }>;
// type Hmm = { foo: string; bar: string; }
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFA3gWAFBSgSzgLigDsBXAWwCMIAnTbAewoCtD0tsoAPQgVjqgC+mIRkyhIUAPLMAysGo4iAcwA8AFQB8SVPwDaABVxEoAawgh6AMyhqAuvn5qDtqBE7AIROAGcojJhAAxsBQAPxQ3vKKSlCETvq2wphi4NAAWtrSTHIKyirwGgDcmAD0AFRQ4unabBy4BMTkVNTF7AzMhJG5Sq0CUGUlyRiB9ESRUJaEWTnR+XBayLX1hAAsADT8-oQARJx7nNtJohhVUAASZGSZslF5KBP09AAUAJSdt0prUBQAhtSEpEoNF0LgERVKJUqqXOlxqD3o726hW+f0R0WRAiAA)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Object` is too general type. Every primitive value in javascript extends `Object` because even numbers and string have their own methods.
Consider this example:

```js
type Check1 = string extends Object ? true : false // true
type Check2 = number extends Object ? true : false // true
```

I think it is better to approach the problem from other side. You can check whether type is primitive or not:

```js
type Id = {
  id: number
  obj: {
    x: 5
  }
}

type Primitives = string | number | boolean | bigint | symbol;

type ObjString<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]:
  T[P] extends Primitives ? T[P] : string
}

const f: ObjString<Id> = {
  id: 4,
  obj: "xxxx"
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFA3gKClAlnAXFAOwFcBbAIwgCcMoB7MgK33U0wA98BWGgXzT7ShIUAAqUsJLMCwA3CAGckUecHEEA5lAA%20hUhUraoZWrQA2EAIYFDZLOqwFgh%20SHJmA3GkHhoAeUYAyqoO6gA8ACoAfEosUADaItjWANYQILQAZlDhALq4NOEJOVAQbMAQBHCKYhJSsgpQAPzZRVD4Kmrq-F4AxrQEKlAZ%20P4MQZ2h8NHIsTj4ACwANDT0TFAARGxbbOvdQA)